# Blackberry: Get screen size without signing

Tags: blackberry, signed

I need to make an absolute layout for a GUI. Is there a way to get the screen size in an UiApplication without using signed code?

Comment: Keys are free now, so there isn't really much of a reason to not go ahead and grab a set. Honestly, you won't be able to do much in an app without having them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net.rim.device.api.system.Display` requires code signing. So in your case you should use some other way.

Hm... actually RIM has several standard dimentions, so you could just google and have a `HashTable` where keys are device model names and values are screen dimensions. Device model name can be got programmatically from `DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()` without signing.

The weak sides of this approach are (1) you'll have to google on each BB device on the market to collect data and (2) you'll have to keep the table updated because RIM may release a new device that would be unknown for your code.